# How to prove the Stoilov's theorem?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

In a book of mine there was Stoilov's theorem which proof was omitted. How can I proof the following?

Every continuous, open, discrete mapping $g$ of a plane can be represented as $g=f\circ h$ where $h$ is a homeomorphism and $f$ is an analytic function.

This is from a complex analysis book so I'm not sure if this holds for all planes or just for a complex plane.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the article [Stoïlow's theorem revisited (arXiv:1701.05726)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05726) discusses the proof of Stoïlow's theorem.

(In fact, a stronger theorem than you state is true: "discrete" can be replaced by "light", which means that the preimage of any point is totally disconnected.)